# How to make border of li appear when you click the li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know if I am speaking correctly, because I am new to HTML. I have a ul menu with four boxes that are li's. I want a box to have a white border if I click that box.

This is my HTML code:

```js
$("ul.quantity-grid li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.quantity-grid li.active{
  border:4px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="quantity-grid">
  <li class="1bag" data-value="1">
    <h3>1 BAG, $35</h3>
    <img src="img/1bag.png">
  </li>

  <li class="2bags" data-value="2">
    <h3>2 BAGS, $45</h3>
    <img src="img/2bags.png">
  </li>

  <li class="3bags" data-value="3">
    <h3>3 BAGS, $65</h3>
    <img src="img/3bags.png">
  </li>

  <li class="4bags" data-value="4">
    <h3>4 BAGS, $55</h3>
    <img src="img/4bags.png">
  </li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is that script in relation to the html on the page?  Is it in the head?

Comment: Yes it's in the head

Comment: Then put your script in a document ready or move it to the bottom of the body.  Your elements do not exist at the point that the head is being parsed into the dom for it to find them and bind on

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/reyffexs/  your code works fine, provided you bind after the elements exist on the page

Answer (score 2):

change your code to like this

```js
    $("ul.quantity-grid li").click(function(){
       
        $('ul.quantity-grid li').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

```css
.quantity-grid {
 background: red;
}
 .quantity-grid li.active{
            border:4px solid #fff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="quantity-grid">
            <li class="1bag" data-value="1">
                <h3>1 BAG, $35</h3>
                <img src="img/1bag.png">
            </li>

            <li class="2bags" data-value="2">
                <h3>2 BAGS, $45</h3>
                <img src="img/2bags.png">
            </li>

            <li class="3bags" data-value="3">
                <h3>3 BAGS, $65</h3>
                <img src="img/3bags.png">
            </li>

            <li class="4bags" data-value="4">
                <h3>4 BAGS, $55</h3>
                <img src="img/4bags.png">
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: see updated answer @KylieRitchie

Comment: this you want? @KylieRitchie

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/reyffexs/  his code works fine.  he just needs to learn about the page life cycle and potentially use a document ready.

Comment: yes @Taplar i think you are right

Comment: i think i answer so soon. without understand that. thank you @Taplar for pointing me out.

Comment: oh i see. thanks @taplar